# Is MKMapView leaky

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, mapkit

As well as my  question "Removing `MKMapView` Annotations causes leaks." I have discovered that if you create a view based project, add a `UISearchBar` and `MKMapView` into the view's NIB, wire up the delegates (I'm not creating any methods as we don't actually need to do anything to trigger the leaks), link in the MapKit and fire up the project, then simply clicking in the `UISearchBar` causes a 1k+ leak.  This doesn't happen unless you have both `UISearchBar` and `MKMapView` in a view.  I have the same issues when creating the views from code. I thought a NIB might behave differently, but it doesn't.

Is `MKMapView` leaky, or am I doing something wrong.

To replicate the issue with code try the code below - I created a new "view based application" project

**TestMapViewFromCodeViewController.h**

```
#import &lt;UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import &lt;MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface TestMapViewFromCodeViewController : UIViewController {
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    MKMapView *mapView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *searchBar;


@end
```

**TestMapViewFromCodeViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar * tmpSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,self.view.frame.size.width,40.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:tmpSearchBar];
    [self setSearchBar:tmpSearchBar];
    [tmpSearchBar release];

    MKMapView *tmpMapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    tmpMapView.showsUserLocation=FALSE;
    [self.view insertSubview:tmpMapView atIndex:0];
    [self setMapView:tmpMapView];
    [tmpMapView release];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [mapView release];
    [searchBar release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Although I've retained the subviews with mapView and searchBar, this is probably unnecessary  to replicate the issue.

In testing this code prior to publishing here I've just noticed that this leak does not occur in the simulator - only on my phone...

Comment: How about some code?  

Based on your self-answer to your other question, I think you should review the memory management guide for the SDK.  I know when I started on the iPhone I got tripped up many times with leaks, because it had been a while since I didn't have a garbage collector.

Comment: No code required - Just drop a UISearchBar and then a MKMapView into a view in IB.  Thats all that's necessary to replicate it. However, I will dig out the code version when I am in front of my Mac.

Comment: code published above. I've also noticed that this leak only happens on my device (not in the simulator). I've not yet updated the iPhone OS version so its still on 3.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There is a known leaks on 3.0's MKMapViews. The leak occurs when you deallocate the MKMapView This is fixed in later releases. The workaround is to have a single MKMapView and reuse it.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/129740#129740

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, there are similar related questions here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935243/mkmapview-rame-et-fuite-memoire-apple
- [Can the memory used by MKMapView be released some how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963498/can-the-memory-used-by-mkmapview-be-released-some-how)
- [MKMapView Memory Leak in iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110102/mkmapview-memory-leak-in-iphone-application)